# Ebay API "The ISBN field is missing. Please add ISBN to the listing and try again." but its there

Tags: python, api, ebay-api

Hopefully you can help as not even the ebay dev forums seem to be able too :S

So i am uploading books, out of 90,000 only 12,000 has listed and i always get this error "The ISBN field is missing. Please add ISBN to the listing and try again." When i print the data being uploaded i get this :-

```
{'availability': {'shipToLocationAvailability': {'quantity': 0}}, 'condition': 'NEW', 'product': {'title': 'Niteblessings : Meditations to close the day', 'description': '', 'aspects': {'format': ['294g'], 'format_title': ['Hardback 208 pages'], 'pagination': ['Hardback 208 pages'], 'imprint': ['Lion Books'], 'edition': ['New ed'], 'ISBN': ['0745981550'], 'published': ['22 Oct 2021'], 'classifications': ['22 Oct 2021'], 'readership': ['22 Oct 2021'], 'dimensions': ['167 x 146 x 18 (mm)'], 'pubCountry': ['United Kingdom'], 'countryOfOrigin': ['GB'], 'tariffCodes': ['49019900'], 'Author': ['In Description'], 'Condition': ['1000'], 'Book Title': ['In Description'], 'Language': ['In Description'], 'Format': ['In Description']}, 'imageUrls': ['https://jackets.dmmserver.com/media/356/97807459/9780745981550.jpg']}}
```

as you can see there is ISBN, i have tried ISBN 13, ISBN 10 etc and all gives me the same error it just makes no sense. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here.

Many thanks :D

Comment: This is a guess, but all the other keys in the dictionary are lower-case. Are you completely sure it should not be `"isbn"`?

Comment: Yep, i forgot to add that. I have tried ISBN and isbn all with the same outcome :(

Comment: It would help if your question included the code necessary to reproduce this error. It sounds like some of your books are uploading correctly; are there any obvious differences between successful requests vs. failed requests?

Comment: The code would not help as you would need access to my tokens. The only thing i can see is some catagorys let me list no issues but some do not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue, Ebay requires the ISBN to be added outside of the product aspects